# Asp.Net: TableSorter not working after update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, tablesorter

My Asp.Net WebSite should show to user some table data. I use TableSorter for sorting this data on client side:

```
<script>var $jQuery171 = jQuery.noConflict();</script>

    <script src="scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $jQuery171(document).ready(function () {
            $jQuery171('#myControl').tablesorter();

        });
    </script>
```

Sorting works great, without any problem, but if I delete current data and insert new from AJAX, sorting is failed.
My code for update table is:

```
function JSonObjectPropertiesToHeader(JSonObject, TableId) {
    $("#" + TableId).empty();
    var tableForProcess = document.getElementById(TableId);
    var header = tableForProcess.createTHead();
    var rowOfHeader = header.insertRow(0);
    for (var propertyName in JSonObject.SourceData[0]) {
        var theadCell = document.createElement('th');
        theadCell.innerHTML = propertyName;
        rowOfHeader.appendChild(theadCell);
    };

    return header;
}    

function JSonObjectsToBody(JSonObjects, RequiredProperties, TableId) {
    var tableForProcess = document.getElementById(TableId);
    var body = tableForProcess.createTBody();
    for (var i = 0, item; item = JSonObjects.SourceData[i]; i++) {
        var rowOfBody = body.insertRow(0);
        for (var propertyName in RequiredProperties) {
            var cellForInsert = rowOfBody.insertCell(rowOfBody.cells.length);
            cellForInsert.innerHTML = item[propertyName];
        }
    };
}
```

and AJAX script:

```
<script>

        function GetDevicesInfoContent() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myUrl",
                data: "{Lang:'tr'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) { OnGetDevicesInfoSuccessContent(response); },
                error: function (response) { OnGetDevicesInfoError(response); }
            })
        }

        function OnGetDevicesInfoSuccessContent(response) {
            var devicesInfoControlId = "<%=report2_gridView.ClientID%>";
            $("#" + devicesInfoControlId).empty();
            if (response.d.length > 0) {
                var jsonObject = eval('(' + response.d + ')');
                var header = JSonObjectPropertiesToHeader(jsonObject, devicesInfoControlId);
                var requiredProperties = [];
                for (var i = 0, cell; cell = header.rows[0].cells[i]; i++) {
                    requiredProperties[cell.innerHTML] = cell.innerHTML;
                };
                JSonObjectsToBody(jsonObject, requiredProperties, devicesInfoControlId);
            }
        }

    function OnGetDevicesInfoErrorContent(response) {
        alert("MyError:" + response.status + " " + response.statusText);
    }

</script>
```

If I apply tablesorter again, then sorting is working. I had never use TableSorter before and I don't know why it failed after update. Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tablesorter is initialized on a table, it adds event bindings to the `thead` cells and processes & creates a cache from the text of each `tbody` cell.

When `$("#" + TableId).empty();` is executed, it is essentially wiping out everything, including event listeners.

If new table built from ajax data has the same header cells & text, then all that needs to be done is to empty the `tbody`. Leave the `thead` alone! After the tbody is rebuilt and in place within the table, you can update tablesorter's cache by triggering an "update" on the table.

```
$("#" + TableId).trigger('update');
```

If the new ajax data does completely change the table, then you will have to reinitialize tablesorter.